# Elmah log4net Appender

Tags: oracle, log4net, elmah, log4net-appender

I'm trying to use [elmah log4net appender](https://github.com/edwinf/log4net---ELMAH-Appender) to log from log4net to oracle database.

Elmah writes correctly on Oracle database when there is an unhandled exception.

But when i call (log4net).Error("foo") Elmah simply ignores it.

Here my config :

```
  <elmah>
      <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
      <errorLog type="Elmah.OracleErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="Euler" />
  </elmah>

<log4net>
    <appender name="elmahappender" type="elmahappender_log4net.ELMAHAppender, elmahappender_log4net">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <UseNullContext>False</UseNullContext>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="(directory)" />
      <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'.log'" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="elmahappender" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

FileAppender works and log data but elmahappender not.

Comment: Found the problem... don't know why but web project doesn't have a reference to elmah log4net appender.

Comment: could you please elaborate on what you did to fix this?

Comment: I simply add a reference to elmahappender_log4net.dll on my web project